# How to change column type with existing data

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have lots of members in my Customer model,

the column role was string type,its value is '1', '2','3'

Now, I want to convert the `role` column type into `integer` type by the following code,

But, When I used the console to check up existing customers role value,

it is still the string type, How can I cast it into integer ? Thanks.

```
  1 class ChangeRoleTypeToCustomers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  2   def up
  3       change_column :customers, :role, 'integer USING CAST(role AS integer)'
  4   end
  5
  6   def down
  7   end
  8 end


irb(main):017:0> c=Customer.where(name:'guest').first
irb(main):018:0> c.role
=> "3"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
change_column :customers, :role, :integer
```